# A 50X error occurred

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install **Magento 2** on my localhost. I can access magento 1.9 files but magento 2 folder is not shown under /localhost.

When I type **localhost/magento-2.3** to URL it says A "50X error occurred - Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please try again later." How to fix this?